# How to untar a tar.gz file in pyspark? The tar.gz has 10 files in it. I'm interested in reading only one file out of the 10

Tags: pyspark

How to untar a tar.gz file in pyspark? The tar.gz has 10 files in it. 
I'm interested in reading only one file out of the 10. I need to untar using pyspark.

Answer (score 0):

by using following command you can untar the file. after that you can read the required file.

**command:**
          sudo tar -xvzf filename.tar.gz